# Is "Cannot be overstated" sloppy writing?

Tags: word-usage

Saying that something "cannot be overstated" is exaggeration and clearly never true, because *anything* can be overstated. (You just keep repeating that thing to the exclusion of everything else: now it is overstated.)

So is using this phrase sloppy writing, or is it a well-understood phase that no longer means what it appears to mean?

Comment: Are you suggesting that exaggeration and overstatement are never useful in good writing? I guess you've never heard of [hyperbole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbole) then, have you?

Comment: That's not what 'overstated' means.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a misunderstanding.

Comment: 'Overstatement' does not mean 'repetition'. It is impossible to overstate something which is definitely, or widely understood, to be at a maximum level. It is impossible to overstate the danger of juggling with bottles of nitroglycerin. Saying that it is 'very dangerous' would never be an overstatement. It is possible to overstate the danger to health of racoon poop on my front porch, e.g. by saying that it is 'very dangerous'.

Answer (score -2):

I consider it sloppy. In general, it is better not to say things that are literally untrue when a true statement could express the same meaning.

Saying something is "hard to overstate" gets the same thing across as saying it "cannot be overstated," but it's less likely to be literally false.